# Extracting Data from Excel Binary file

Tags: microsoft-office-2007

I need to write a macro to extract data from an Excel Binary file and tabulate it in a different excel file. The source excel file has sheets recorded in individual cells. Can this be done and if yes, how does one go about it?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this can be done using VBA scripting.

There are lots of tutorials on how to program in VBA, one for instance is here: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html